# Importing a Subversion repository with a non-standard layout into Git

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to (permanently) migrate my group's Subversion repository to Git, but I'm running onto problems trying to clean up its non-standard directory structure.

Some of the project's content is contained in trunk and branches folders, but not all of it. The project on Subversion is laid out like this:

```
project/trunk/
project/branches/feature_1
project/branches/feature_2
project/libraries
project/crontab
...
```

After importing, I want the Git repository to be laid out like so:

```
project/html # the content of the old trunk and branches folders
project/libraries
project/crontab
...
```

Running `svn2git` with the appropriate options will handle the trunk and branches directories correctly, but how can I also include the history for the other folders? It seems like `git-filter-branch` could help, but I'm not sure how to use it for this.

Comment: The (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614229/can-i-move-the-git-directory-for-a-repo-to-its-parent-directory) may help.

Comment: why not you make a 'svn move' to get the appropriate structure and then do a svn2git ? you will still have the history right ?

Comment: @Version Control Buddy: After the import, the Git repository will consider the old `project/trunk` folder to be its root. Folders `svn move`d into trunk before the import will have history, but their original locations will still be outside the root of the repository, and they will be ignored.

Comment: I feel it would not get left out, but I dont have the time now to validate my statement. However, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292531 this seems similar to your requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When converting from svn to git using git-svn or svn2git, how can I change the base path of the repository and possibly still keep branches/tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292531/when-converting-from-svn-to-git-using-git-svn-or-svn2git-how-can-i-change-the-ba)

Comment: @EricNaeseth You said "Folders `svn move` d into trunk before the import....will be ignored." - would this mean that `git blame` wouldn't work for those folders?  Just as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6986090/277208) asks about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import each main subfolder of your repo into a separate git repo and then use the [subtree merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) method to merge the git repos into one repo. You may end up with a few duplicate commits though.

If you have many subdirectories you may want to do an `svnadmin dump`, then `svndumpfilter exclude ..` twice to split your svn repo into two halves and then use the subtree merging method to re-join them. This would have a cleaner history than doing many subtree merges.